# How to access an array that is in a different HTML page? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array on my INDEX.html page.

```
var itemsArr = [ ];
```

On a different HTML page, I would like to add one item to the array that is located in the INDEX.html page.

```
itemsArr.push("add this");
```

Is that possible? I read several answers for similar questions, but they all seem a bit too complicated. This is for an assignment and I'm not very knowledgeable in JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the array to be updated on page A, then page B is loaded with the modified version of the array? This is not possible and you should look into cookies if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use cookies or localstorage.